How to use the slack response for updating azure alert rule
I Want to update the alert Rule status to Acknowledged or Close from slack channel for that I have created HTTP Action block in Azure logic app with below code structure and it will post the message in the slack channel .
Would like to know the logic how to send the selected response from slack to azure portal
Here is the HTTP action that I configured in Logic APP


{
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "section",
      "block_id": "alert_info_section",
      "text": {
        "type": "mrkdwn",
        "text": ":azure: :alert: \n*Non-Prod Alert: Dummy*\n*Severity*: dummy\n*Timestamp*: dummy \n*Alert Id*: ```dummy```\n\nClick <https://repo.com to find the pull request for Terraform plan output\n*****************************************************\n*Affected resource: dummy* \n*Resource modified by:dummy*\n*****************************************************\n"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "divider"
    },
    {
      "type": "section",
      "block_id": "state_section",
      "text": {
        "type": "mrkdwn",
        "text": "*Select a response:*"
      },
      "accessory": {
        "type": "static_select",
        "action_id": "response_select",
        "placeholder": {
          "type": "plain_text",
          "text": "Choose an option"
        },
        "options": [
          {
            "text": {
              "type": "plain_text",
              "text": "New"
            },
            "value": "new"
          },
          {
            "text": {
              "type": "plain_text",
              "text": "Acknowledged"
            },
            "value": "acknowledged"
          },
          {
            "text": {
              "type": "plain_text",
              "text": "Closed"
            },
            "value": "closed"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}



Here is the slack response :

So while select the one of the option that response i want to send back to logic app in portal or ADO pipeline two approach I can try .

It is not feasible to achieve

is there any alternative option ?

its possible to achieve by https://api.slack.com/interactivity/handling
